# How to link to a custom template in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to add a link to a button in Shopify, but I can't get it to work. 
I created a new template file in Templates called "page.alternate.liquid"
Then I try to link to it from header using this:

```
 <a href="{{ routes.page.alternate_url }}" class="header__logo-link">LINK</a>
```

The output doesn't add any link at all, just a regular text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view an alternate template, you have two options:

1) On the resource in question, choose the template that the resource should default to using the selector on the right-hand side.

(Note: this only shows if you have at least 1 appropriate alternate theme in the *live* theme, and will only list the alternate templates in the currently-live theme)

2) When linking to the resource, add `view=<template-suffix>` to the querystring of the link.

Example: To link to an alternate page template `templates/page.inverted_colours.liquid`, your link URL would be `/pages/about-us?view=inverted_colours`

In your case in the question, that would look something like `<a href=" {{ page.url }}?view=alternate_url" class="header__logo-link">LINK</a>`

This article on Shopify partners blog might help as well: https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/shopify-alternate-templates

Hope this helps!